# Keycloak client for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, keycloak

Is there any existing Keycloak client for Asp.net Core? [I have found a NuGet package for .net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Keycloak) but it doesn't work with Core. Do you have any ideas how to easily integrate with this security server (or maybe using any other alternatives)?

Comment: Have you found any resources for this?

Comment: Try using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect with OpenIdConnectOptions filled for Keycloak (Authority: server+"auth/realms/"+realm, ClientId, ClientSecret).

Comment: @mikes do you know of an online sample of this configuration you are suggesting with AspNetCore and keycloak? Just out of curiosity, why don't you provide your answer below in the answer as opposed to a comment? Wondering of the difference in SO...

Comment: @Talisker just didn't think about it. ;) The answer is available right now.

Comment: Won't this library help here - https://github.com/lvermeulen/Keycloak.Net

Comment: It might, but I'm kind of off this problem for a few years already. Thanks for the bump tho! :)

Comment: Is Keycloak.net still supported? The docs are no longer available.

Comment: I have no idea. I don't work with .net any more.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've played a bit with this today. The most straightforward way is too use OpenId standard.

In Startup.cs I used OpenIdConnect Authentication:

```
    public void Configure(...)
    { (...)
         app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
        });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateKeycloakOpenIdConnectOptions());`(...)
 }`
```

OpenIdConnectOptions method:

```
private OpenIdConnectOptions CreateKeycloakOpenIdConnectOptions()
    {
        var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            Authority = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ServerAddress"]+"/auth/realms/"+ Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:Realm"],
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false, //only in development
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
            ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ClientSecret"],
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            SaveTokens = true

        };
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        return options;
    }
```

In appsettings.json add configuration for Keycloak:

```js
{
  (...),
  "Authentication": {
    "KeycloakAuthentication": {
      "ServerAddress": "http://localhost:8180",
      "Realm": "demo",
      "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:57630/",
      "ClientId": "KeycloakASPNETCore",
      "ClientSecret": "secret-get-it-in-keycloakConsole-client-credentials"
    }
  }
}
```

Keycloak  client is configuerd as followed:

- [Client settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VINc.png),
- [I've added 'accounting' role for test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVE5h.png),
- [I added mapper 'member_of' of type 'User Client Role' for roles so that roles are added in the claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK848.png)

If I want to Authorize user by role I do something like this:

Add [authorization by claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims) in ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        (...)

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Accounting", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("member_of", "[accounting]")); //this claim value is an array. Any suggestions how to extract just single role? This still works.
        });
    }
```

I've edited get method in ValuesController (Default Web API template):

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Accounting")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values        
    [HttpGet]
    public Dictionary<string,string> Get()
    {
        var userPrinciple = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var claims = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var claim in userPrinciple.Claims)
        {
            var key = claim.Type;
            var value = claim.Value;

            claims.Add(key, value);
        }


        return claims;
    }
```

If I login with user that has accounting role or is in group that has accounting role, it should display my user claims on address localhost:57630/api/values.

I hope this works for you.

**Edit: .NET Core 2**
Hi everyone! The way my app works changed quite a bit and I have not fully tested .NET Core 2 yet, but you can still try connecting to Keycloak like this in ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {

                options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ServerAddress"] + "/auth/realms/" + Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:Realm"];
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = new string[] { "curl", "financeApplication", "accountingApplication", "swagger"}
                };
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; //for test only!
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.Validate();

            });
```

And in Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

You can access your token later with IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, for example:

```
public KeycloakAuthorizationRequirementHandler(IConfiguration config,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
            IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            _config = config;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }
```

//get accessToken

```
var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["username"] = username;
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Very useful and complete answer! The only thing I can't get to work is the mapper `member_of`, it's not present in the list of user claims. Would you mind sharing the settings you used to create it? Thanks.

Comment: You can create 'member_of' by clicking 'Create' in the 'Mappers' tab of your client. 'Mapper Type' should be set to 'User Client Role' and 'Add to ID token' - on. After you logout your user, changes should be visible in user claims.

Comment: @gimly If user has more than 1 role, you can authorize by using Custom Policy-Based Authorization where you check each of your users roles.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the reason why I couldn't see it on the claims was that I hadn't given a claim name. Now it's working correctly.

Comment: @frogec could you give an example of authorizing a user who has more than one role in keycloak? I am normally in the javaworld nowadays but now I have to create a PoC for .net core and don't get it to work with more than one role :/

Comment: okay, actually this seems to be outdated as of .net core 2. Would be great to get an update! :)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use standard .Net Role mappings with Keycloak Client Roles, setup like so:

Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Users", policy =>
        policy.RequireRole("Users"));
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:oidc:Authority"]
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:oidc:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:oidc:ClientSecret"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/SignOut";
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "Redirect-here";
        options.ResponseType = "code";

    });
```

appsettings.json:

```
  "Authentication": {
    "oidc": {
      "Authority":"http://your-keycloak-server/auth/realms/your-realm",
      "ClientId":"Your-Client-Name",
      "ClientSecret":"Your-client-secret"
    }
  }
```

Keycloak Client Settings:

- Create new Token Mapper
- [Mapper-Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFmtG.jpg)  (enter your own client name)

Now you can use standard authorize role statements to apply your Keycloak Client Roles to your ASP.NET project:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Users")]
```

Comment: just to be clear: for /Signout I should use the logout-endpoint of my keycloak-realm, shouldn't I? Or did you create a ressource under /signout which calls that internally and creates a logoutpage or something?

Comment: Either will work, just depends on what you're requirements are. If you need to intercept any portion of the logout process, say to keep the user on your UI instead of redirecting to keycloak, then you would create your own signout and implement the keycloak API to logout. Otherwise, the keycloak logout endpoint will suffice.

Comment: Also to be clear, the above configuration will check keycloak, automatically get the signout path, and assign it to "/SignOut" in your application. This is the options.RemoteSignOutPath configuration setting.

Comment: Hey, I am having trouble logging out. The app re-authenticates the user automatically. I am calling: `do! ctx.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` and `do! ctx.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` (I used F# with Saturn). Any idea what's wrong? Is there anything special that has to be done upon logging out?

Answer (score 2):

For those who building KeyCloak-based authentication for .Net 6 backend and looking for JWT-token based solution here is a code to add in ConfigureServices of your app with [Delobytes.AspNetCore.Infrastructure](https://github.com/a-postx/Delobytes.AspNetCore.Infrastructure/blob/master/README.en.md) client:

```
services.AddKeyCloakAuthentication("SchemeName", true, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://mykeycloakinstallation.com/auth/realms/myrealm"; //"issuer" endpoint
        options.Audience = "account";
        options.OpenIdConfigurationEndpoint = "https://mykeycloakinstallation.com/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationOptions
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "https://mykeycloakinstallation.com/auth/realms/myrealm",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "account",
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing that worked for us was setting these things in Startup.cs (it's cookie based authentication):

```
public void Configure(...)
{
    (...)
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        CookieHttpOnly = true,
        CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOpenIdConnectOptions(_customConfig));
    (...)
}
```

And setting up the options:

```
private OpenIdConnectOptions CreateOpenIdConnectOptions(CustomConfigurationFile configuration)
{
    var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
        SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        Authority = configuration.ServerAddress + "/auth/realms/" + configuration.Realm,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = configuration.SystemAddress,
        ClientId = configuration.ClientId,
        ClientSecret = configuration.ClientSecret,
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
        GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
        SaveTokens = true
    };
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Does this solution allow you to use standard authorization attributes such as [Autorize(Roles="MyKeycloakRole")] ? In other terms, are KeyCloak-defined roles extracted automatically through OpenIdConnectAuthentication? cheers

Comment: @Talisker did you find a solution / answer to this? Otherwise keycloak and your service is strongly coupled.

Answer (score 1):

Could we get an up-to-date answer on this question with .net core 5+?  I've recently installed keycloak version 13.0.0 & its working allowing me to use single sign on with a couple apps.  Now for the real reason I installed keycloak, for webapi authentication.  Based on the answers above I've installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect & have been working to get this to work on both the webapi side and on the client side.

Comment: You can try to use this library https://github.com/lvermeulen/Keycloak.Net