# OpenID Connect Integration

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

*ASP.NET Boilerplate* unlike *ASP.NET Zero* does not contain the OpenID Connect support to a third-party Identity Solution.

An older post on the ASP.NET Boilerplate forum ([Support for Open ID and JWT?](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5278&sid=3dc95c62333a5583d19938de8151fc6a)) discusses this topic but does not provide any code example on how to approach this. Has anyone tried this already?

It would be fine if this feature could be added to ASP.NET Boilerplate as well...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not, since I didn't conclude this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your application openid connect client (not server) you can just use Microsoft's related nuget package.

If your application is ASP.NET Core then the package name is [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/)

But if you want to be an open id connect server, it's a different thing. You can then use Identity Server for example.

Comment: Yes this is clear. But does there exist a code example or at least an enumeration of the necessary steps to get it working?

I tried for instance the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721032/keycloak-client-for-asp-net-core but just adding app.UseCookieAuthentication() and app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() in Configure() is not enough.

Comment: The last forum post states something like "I can share our OpenId Connect configuration code here if you like to try it with the free templates." (https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5278&sid=3dc95c62333a5583d19938de8151fc6a#p12988). It would be fine if this could happen, unfortunately the forum has been locked in the meantime.