# OpenID Connect Integration with template

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I've got a question on the best way to implement OpenID with aspnetboilerplate. 
I've looked and browsed on the net and I can't seem to find anything that is clear cut to me. 
I'm wondering if Has anyone got some OpenID example code to implement with Aspnet boiler plate?

I already have a Identity Service instance I need to log in to, but I can't see the way I'd hook up my project too it.

I've tried looking at the [external providers documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management?searchKey=external#external-authentication) documentation, but that doesn't seem to list it in the JWT External Auth providers.

Comment: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=15861 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819566/1767482

Comment: Hi Alper Yeah i have seen these resources but I haven't been able to make a clear cut sense of what exactly to do.

Comment: @PhillipMorton Did you find a clean solution for integrating ABP with IdSrv as a client? Are you using Angular SPA template or Multi Page Web Application?