# Secure ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app with KeyCloak

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, keycloak, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to secure my ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app with KeyCloak.

I tried few things:

- I used some of the examples available but they are either deprecated or done in .NET Core 2.1
- I found some KeyCloak adapters for .NET Core but they are not maintained for so long.
- I found one GitHub repo from [thinktecture-labs webinar for keycloak](https://github.com/thinktecture-labs/webinar-keycloak) securing Angular app and API but could not figure out the KeyCloak client configuration as well as how to connect it to ASP.NET Core MVC app in a similar way.

I would really appreciate it if you can guide me with any blog, GitHub repo, or a simple example that shows how to secure an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app with KeyCloak. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use keycloak-specific libraries to integrate Keycloak with ASP.NET Core 3.1. You can use JWT token authentication / authorization libraries instead.

Sample:
Add the following lines to your appsettings.json file. Please don't forget to change the  section to your realm name.

```
"JWT": {
  "Issuer": "https://<keycloakdomain>/auth/realms/<realmname>",
  "Audience": "account, <realmname>, <anotherrealmname>"
}
```

You can type the following code into your startup.cs file.

```
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Authority = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"];
                x.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context => { return Task.CompletedTask; },
                    OnTokenValidated = context => { return Task.CompletedTask; }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudiences = (Configuration["JWT:Audience"]).Split(','),
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
                    ValidateLifetime = false
                };
        
                x.Validate();
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = autFailed =>
                    {
                        autFailed.NoResult();
                        autFailed.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        autFailed.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                        return autFailed.Response.WriteAsync(autFailed.Exception.ToString());
                    }
                };
            });
```

After these operations, you can see the token validation by sending Bearer  ... as the Authorization header value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @OnderD for your prompt response. I am wondering how do I configure the KeyCloak for this client, which "Access type" to choose, "Confidential" or "Bearer Only"? How do I configure it so that it will work for the role-based Authorization?

Comment: You can choose "Confidential". And you can choose Authorization Enable = true for RBAC

Comment: Then how should I introduce the ClientId and ClientSecret in my Startup.cs or in appsettings.json. Can I introduce roles in the controller's action like [Authorize(Roles = "Customer-Admin")]?  Most of the information I found for this approach is for Core API but I couldn't find any appropriate ones for the MVC. Do you think this approach is good for the .Net Core MVC app? I followed the answer by @Imagin8 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41721032/keycloak-client-for-asp-net-core). RBAC is working but while inspecting in jwt.io I can't see roles and profile parameters in the access token.